# Corollary 2.1 in Ekeland and Temam on lower semicontinuity

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, calculus-of-variations

Why in Corollary 2.1 on page 10 (see the picture) from Ekeland and Temam book *Convex Analysis and Variational Problems* there is equality in (2.11), i.e why
$$\forall u\in V,\quad \overline F(u)=\liminf\limits_{v\to u}{F(v)}$$

I only see the obvious relation $\overline F(u)\leq \liminf\limits_{v\to u}{F(v)}$. This follows from the fact that $\overline F(v)\leq F(v),\,\forall v\in V$ and thus
 $$\liminf\limits_{v\to u}{\overline F(v)}\leq \liminf\limits_{v\to u}{F(v)}$$
But also $\overline F$ is lower semi-continuous, so we get 
$$\overline F(u)\leq \liminf\limits_{v\to u}{\overline F(v)}\leq \liminf\limits_{v\to u}{F(v)}$$

**Another observation**: If $F$ is convex and l.s.c, then $F$ coincides with its $\Gamma$-regularization, i.e $\Gamma(F)=F$. Then we have $\overline F=F$. This follows from the inequality $\Gamma(F)\leq \overline F\leq F$. Here, the $\Gamma$-regularization is the pointwise supremum of all affine minorants of $F$. The above observation means that for convex and l.s.c functionals, the lower semicontinuity property is no longer inequality, but equality.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the line "Let $G$ be a function such that ..."
should continue with 
"... $\text{epi} G = \overline{\text{epi} F}$".

Take this $G$. Its epigraph is the closure of $\text{epi} F$, i.e. the smallest closed set to contain $\text{epi} F$. Thus there cannot be any l.s.c. function $\bar{F} \leq F$ with $G(v) < \bar{F}(v)$ in some point $v$. Therefore $G = \bar{F}$.

To check (2.11), let's define $H(u) := \liminf_{v \to u} F(v)$. Then $G \leq H$, because the liminf is taken over a larger set to define $G$. 
Moreover, $H \leq F$ and $H$ is "obviously" l.s.c. But $G$ is the largest one with these properties, hence $G = H$.

(Note that the closure of the epigraph means the topological closure and in liminf you use filters. If you take sequential closure instead, you can/should use sequences.)

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand  the part where $G=\bar F$. But I still can not see how (2.11) follows. If $v_n\to u$ in $V$ (consider only sequential l.s.c and sequential closedness), then how can we show $\bar F(u)=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}{F(v_n)}$ ?
 If we take $(u,a):=(u,\bar F(u))\in epi\bar F=\overline{epi F}$, then by (1) in the footnote, taking $b:=\bar F(u)+\epsilon_n$, $\epsilon_n\to 0$, we get $(u,\bar F(u)+\epsilon_n)\in epi F,\,\forall n$ and I am stuck.

Comment: @Svetoslav: I see, thanks. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot digest it: If we work only with sequences (enough for me), then $H(u)$ would depend on the sequence $v_n$ converging to $u$. I even do not know what the $\liminf\limits_{v\to u}{F(v)}$  means in a non-metric topological space.

Comment: @Svetoslav: Well, (2.11) cannot be true if in $\underline{lim}$ we can choose one particular sequence, right? It makes more sense if it means the infimum over all sequences, also. (I checked the book, superficially, but found no definition.)